# It displaying error message while am running the file

Tags: jmeter

after giving the testing URL and run the file it showing the error message like "Uncaught Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService. See log file for details."

Created thread group
added http sampler
added listner

error message is "Uncaught Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService. See log file for details."

Answer (score 1):

This might happen, when a Dependent jar is not present or in case if there is a conflicting jar with different implementation present.
Try to download a fresh copy or check the lib folders dont have multiple version of the same jar.
Hope this helps.

Comment: how to add jar files in jmeter

Comment: Go to jmeter>lib there you can find all the jars. If you download plugin then it will be placed under jmeter>lib>ext..